# How can I programmatically read a Adobe DRM'd Epub?

Tags: adobe, drm, epub

I am writing an ebook reader that supports the epub format (i have the parsing of open epub working), but I would like to support the reading of Adobe DRM locked epubs.

I have read through the Adobe digital editions site (faq and support pages) and googled, but alas as yet I have not found any docs on the API to:

1. authorise the PC using the user's Adobe ID credentials and
2. decrypt the epub for parsing by my app.

Does anyone have any pointers to docs or APIs?

I would prefer APIs in Python, C++. But any API is better than nothing ;-)

UPDATE1: I am writing my app on Desktops (linux, mac and windows).

UPDATE2: Just to be clear, I am assuming that user has paid for the book legitimately and so does have an Adobe ID. I don't want to crack the DRM, just allow the user to read their books that they bought.

Comment: Thanks APC for doing the grammar fixes, much appreciated attention to detail.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the solution is to license the Adobe Mobile Reader SDK:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/readermobile/